# Error on SELECT * INTO statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to transfer all data from one table into another with the following code:

```
INSERT INTO tblpremier 
   SELECT * INTO #TempTable
   FROM dbo.IntermediateTable

ALTER TABLE #TempTable
DROP COLUMN id

SELECT * FROM #TempTable
```

And I get an error

> *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'*

at the second line of this code. Any help?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've written doesn't make any sense. The first "statement" is this:

```
INSERT INTO tblpremier 
SELECT * INTO #TempTable
FROM dbo.IntermediateTable
```

Now are you inserting into #temptable, or tblpremier? I'm guessing you wanted to perform all these operations and then insert into `tblpremier` - in which case split it into separate statements. I'm guessing you wanted to do:

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable
FROM dbo.IntermediateTable

ALTER TABLE #TempTable
DROP COLUMN id

INSERT INTO tblpremier
SELECT * FROM #TempTable
```

But rather than need `#Temptable` which is the same as `IntermediateTable` minus the ID column, why not just select the correct columns you need from `IntermediateTable` in the first place rather than using `*`?

**Edit:**

Here's what I meant. Write the insert statement so you've got all the column names specified, and don't include the ID column. You'll get all new ID numbers on the copy of the table.

```
INSERT INTO tblpremier (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM IntermediateTable
```

However, if you wanted to to keep the same ID numbers in the copy of the table, and the columns are in the same order on both `intermediate` table and `tblpremier`, then you could write:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblpremier ON

INSERT INTO tblpremier
SELECT * 
FROM IntermediateTable

SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblpremier OFF
```

But you would still need to watch out for trying to insert duplicate IDs if `tblpremier` isn't empty at first.

Comment: i get the following error Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'tblpremier' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column.  (I set the identity_insert to ON) but is still the same error

Comment: @user1292656 Why not show us the schema of the table you're trying to import into, and the schema of the intermediate table rather than have us guess?

Comment: they are exactly the same tables!

Comment: @user1292656 This is again another reason why it's much better to specify which columns you want to insert into, and which columns to select from.

Comment: @user1292656 - I've edited my original post with some new options for you.

Comment: i specified the columns and again i get the error 'Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'tblpremier' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column.
'

Comment: @user1292656 I assume you forgot to turn off identity insert before trying it!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use both `INSERT INTO TABLE SELECT  FROM` and `SELECT INTO` at the same time. You should break that statement into

```
INSERT INTO tblpremier 
SELECT * FROM dbo.IntermediateTable

SELECT * INTO #TempTable
FROM dbo.IntermediateTable

ALTER TABLE #TempTable
DROP COLUMN id

SELECT * FROM #TempTable
```

Comment: Your interpretation doesn't make any sense. You're copying straight from the `intermediate` table to the `tblpremier` table here - so what's the point of the temp table in this context?

Comment: per my understanding, I thought temptable contains the data from intermediate table without the id column, @Bridge. May be that is incorrect, probably OP can confirm that.

Comment: @Victor Judging by the comments OP left on my answer, I'm not entirely sure the OP knows what he wants after all ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have both a `SELECT INTO` and `INSERT INTO` in the same statement.